# Davening in the wrong direction in a shul

Tags: halacha, tefilla

If a local shul has the Aron Kodesh in the wrong direction  (northwest) because they took over a Conservative shul and never changed the structure and they daven towards the Aron instead of turning to the right  - - is it OK to daven there if there are other options available?  Can I daven facing Yerushalayim/East even if all the other people davening are facing Northwest?

Comment: I face a similar situation and a Rabbi said one should daven as the rest of the congregation does but if possible tilt your head a bit in the direction of Jerusalem.

Comment: I have been told to face the ark, even when it is not eastward, out of respect for the Torah (or perhaps out of not wanting to disrespect it by praying with your back or side towards the ark).

Comment: I think the easier thing is just to move the Aron HaKodesh. :P

Answer (score 3):

See SA, Magen Avraham and Machatsit Hashekel [OC 94 sk 2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x463) :

> שולחן ערוך: ב אִם מִתְפַּלֵּל לְרוּחַ מִשְּׁאָר (ב) רוּחוֹת, יְצַדֵּד פָּנָיו לְצַד אֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל אִם הוּא בְּחוּץ לָאָרֶץ; וְלִירוּשָׁלַיִם, אִם הוּא בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל; וְלַמִּקְדָּשׁ, אִם הוּא בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם ‏
>
> מגן אברהם: פי' במקום שמנהגם כך או שיושב על החמור:‏
>
> מחצית השקל: דקשיא ליה, למה באמת מתפלל לשאר רוחות, ולזה כתב שמנהג המקום כן הוא ואינו רוצה לשנות מן המנהג. ובאמת המנהג שלא כדין וכמו שכתב הרב בית יוסף בשם מהרי"א דיש מקומות שנוהגין כן ‏{‏ אמר @קותי, יש להבין שהם נוהגים שלא כדין אבל לפי סברת אחד מן הפוסקים ‏} ‏ וכתב הט"ז אם על פי טעות עמד לצפון או לדרום איכא האי תקנתא להפוך את פניו לצד מזרח אבל אם העמיד את עצמו ופניו למערב דאי אפשר לתקן על ידי היפוך פניו דאכתי לא יהיה פניו למזרח אין צריך לעקור רגליו בשביל זה ולעמוד לצד מזרח ויש לסמוך על האי מאן דאמר בפרק לא יחפור דשכינה בכל מקום. ‏

As said one user in comment: `I face a similar situation and a Rabbi said one should daven as the rest of the congregation does but if possible tilt your head a bit in the direction of Jerusalem. – code613`. And we need to add that if it is impossible to tilt your head because you are in the opposite wall, you can continue to pray with the congregation and be quite according the opinion which says that Shechina is in all places.

The [Mishna Berura sk 10](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=249&hilite=) agrees with this Psak.

Comment: Great article with sources here: http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2015/11/which-direction.html

Comment: Large chunks of untranslated text should not be cited. Rather a summary should be presented. Is your penultimate paragraph a summary of the text? Consider clarifying.